# Adding and Using Dynamic Libraries with Xcode

Tags: xcode, opencv, linker, mach-o, dynamic-library

Ok. So here goes. I am currently trying to add and use a dynamic library called OpenCV into a Xcode project of mine. I first installed MacPorts using the .pkg. Then I opened Terminal and ran "sudo port install opencv". MacPorts then installed all sorts of dependencies (FFMPEG/etc) and then installed OpenCV into the "/opt/local/lib" folder for the .dylib files and into "/opt/local/include" folder for the header files. Then I opened Xcode and opened command line utility application project. I added a group to my project and then added all the .dylib files inside of it (I think these are called references to the dynamic libraries, but I am not sure - I am a total beginner - I learned C++, my first programming language, merely a week ago"). After that, I clicked on my project file thing inside of Xcode and went to Build Settings and then changed the "Header Search Paths" under the "Search Paths" tab to the /include folder I mentioned previously. The Library Search Path was already set to the /lib folder since I added the .dylib files already (I think that's what happened - not sure). Anyways, then I copied and pasted the following sample code from the opencv website into my main.cpp file just to test whether or not my library works.

//******************************Sample Code ************************************************

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
if( argc != 2) {
    cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
    return -1; }
Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
if(! image.data ) {
    // Read the file
    // Check for invalid input
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1; }
namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.
waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0; }
```

//********************END OF SAMPLE FILE CODE **********************************************

After I did all that and before I hit run, I think it is important to note that Xcode did not complain that it couldn't find my header files, and also it didn't complain about any syntax errors with the new functions the library should've added. In short, there were no errors highlighted on the main.cpp file. All the errors, however, started showing up after I hit the Run button inside of Xcode. Here are all the errors that it generated:

**************Errors from Xcode after I hit Run*********************************************

Stupid Stack Overflow won't let me post images, so here is the link to the error photo:
[image]

*****************END OF BLOCK***************************************************************
So, yeah, I have no clue what I am doing at this point and am totally lost. Did I not follow the correct steps in adding a dynamic library to my project? Oh, and I forgot what it was, but I somehow got Xcode to ignore those semantic issues (I cannot remember how I did this or if that was what I did), but once the semantic issues are ignore, the only error that remains seems to be something related to a "Mach-O Linker Error" which says something on the lines of: "undefined symbols....architecture/etc" and then says that the undefined symbol was one of the library functions that I was calling in my main.cpp file. But that error no longer occurs since I deleted everything and started again. So now the only errors I get are the ones from the picture. So PLEASE HELP!!!! I am absolutely lost and I have been researching for weeks now, but I think the issue with me there is that I have no clue what I am looking for or what question I should be asking. The steps I listed above is only what I have done. Any insight will be much appreciated. THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!!!

____________EDIT___________________
So I repeated the above steps again, but this time I get this error:
Ld /Users/Yash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVOptTEST-adchdkiefzmijfhahwtzcfqarzkw/Build/Products/Debug/OpenCVOptTEST normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/Yash/Coding Folder/OpenCVOptTEST"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/Yash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVOptTEST-adchdkiefzmijfhahwtzcfqarzkw/Build/Products/Debug -L/opt/local/lib -F/Users/Yash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVOptTEST-adchdkiefzmijfhahwtzcfqarzkw/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Yash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVOptTEST-adchdkiefzmijfhahwtzcfqarzkw/Build/Intermediates/OpenCVOptTEST.build/Debug/OpenCVOptTEST.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OpenCVOptTEST.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -lopencv_calib3d.2.4.6 -lopencv_contrib.2.4.6 -lopencv_core.2.4.6 -lopencv_features2d.2.4.6 -lopencv_flann.2.4.6 -lopencv_gpu.2.4.6 -lopencv_highgui.2.4.6 -lopencv_imgproc.2.4.6 -lopencv_legacy.2.4.6 -lopencv_ml.2.4.6 -lopencv_nonfree.2.4.6 -lopencv_objdetect.2.4.6 -lopencv_photo.2.4.6 -lopencv_stitching.2.4.6 -lopencv_superres.2.4.6 -lopencv_ts.2.4.6 -lopencv_video.2.4.6 -lopencv_videostab.2.4.6 -o /Users/Yash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVOptTEST-adchdkiefzmijfhahwtzcfqarzkw/Build/Products/Debug/OpenCVOptTEST

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

---

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apple's [documentation for working with Dynamic Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/dynamiclibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html).

What these errors are telling you is that it can't find the object code (implementations) for these symbols during the Linking phase. From Apple's documentation, it looks like it expects to find the dylibs in /usr/local/lib not /opt/local/lib.